# Align a floating component to the top right of a container with ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have a floating component (a panel), I want to align it to the top-right corner of a container.

For the moment, I'm just able to align it to the top-left corner
The component have this listener :

```
        listeners: {
            afterrender: function() {
                this.setPosition(0,0)
            },
        }
```

Problem, the container the component should be align width has an undefined size has it may resize according to the screen resolution.

How can I manage it ?

I've checked the alignTo method but can't make it work !

Any idea ?
I would do the same with bottom-left corner too !

I can provide some more codes if needed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the alignTo method as follows;

```
listeners: {
  afterrender: function(cmp, eOpts) {
     cmp.alignTo(Ext.getBody(), 'tl-tl');
 }
}
```

That should do it, for a bottom right alignment use 'br-br'. If you want to address the screen resizing, put a listener on the viewport resize event and just re-run the alignTo on the component.